# Strange autocompletion result in emacs + common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, slime, completion

I am using Emacs with SLIME for my development environment. When I type `(write-to` and then `C-M-i` I get the following autocompletions:

```
Click on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
write-to-sting
write-to-string
```

I know Common Lisp is powerful, but I guess `write-to-sting` is not in the ANSI standard. Google didn't offer a single hit for this function. Then I tried to find it in the SBCL code, but [alas](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=write-to-sting&type=Code)

`(documentation 'write-to-sting 'function)` returns `nil` so it doesn't have a documentation string.

When I try to execute the function `(write-to-sting)` I get `The function COMMON-LISP-USER::WRITE-TO-STING is undefined.`

Apropos also finds an unbound function:

```
(apropos 'write-to)
WRITE-TO
WRITE-TO-STING
WRITE-TO-STRING (fbound)
```

My question is: **What is going on?** Does anyone knows the story behind this function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At some point during your interaction with the Lisp environment, *you* wrote `write-to-sting` and it was read by the Lisp reader. The symbol was interned in the COMMON-LISP-USER package. After all, maybe you intended to implement a function that sends an email to Sting, who knows?
Auto-completion works by filtering the currently known symbols in the environment.

You can safely `(unintern 'write-to-sting)` (or implement it).

Comment: *facepalm* I did the following test: I wrote (blablabla), exited the debugger and then (apropos 'bla) showed the function... So you are correct - mistyping the function interns the mistyped version...